# Correct usage of the verb "tense"

Tags: verbs, past-participles

*Are you **tense**?*

I read this question in a book and was debating if it was a correct usage of the verb 'tense'.
I believe the correct usage should be

*Are you **tensed**?*

Am I right about this?

Comment: it's not a verb, it's an adjective

Comment: 'Are you tensed?' means something quite different. Roughly speaking, it means 'Are you ready and primed for action?'

Comment: I tense when someone discusses past participles.

Comment: Yes indeed, I wasn't thinking of tense as an adjective.

Comment: FWIW: One example, out of many, of how punctuation affects meaning: “Americans like to live in the present tense.” versus “Americans like to live in the present, tense.”

Answer (score 3):

*Tense* is also an adjective. See the definition in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tense) and [the ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tense). Hence, *Are you tense*? is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tense is the correct form of this adjective (state of being)

> OED 2.2 fig. In a state of nervous or mental strain or tension;
>   strained; highly strung; ‘on the stretch’; excited, or excitable;
>   keenly sensitive.

Comment: @CarSmack: Thanks for the warning. Since the word "tense" has many different and similar meanings, I thought that giving the precise definition in question rather than just linking to a dictionary added something crucial.